# Is "One's life of them" a valid phrase?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, possessives

I want to use a phrase that takes the form of possession. It may be a matter of *an apostrophe with s* or *a usage of a possessive pronoun*, I suppose.

What I want the phrase to mean and indicate is that there are two individuals whom I want to talk about the life of only one of them instantaneously.

The sentence (not the original one):

> They were always together until destiny took away ______ (one's life of them?).

I want the phrase to be a substitute of **the life of one of them**.

I would also like to know if there are other ways of stating the phrase in a shortened form.

Comment: Just drop the "of them" and say "They were always together until destiny took away one's life." Shorter: They were always together until one's death."

Comment: Robusto, 'One's life' is ambiguous.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Don't look now, but *one of their lives* is also ambiguous. The extra words add nothing but padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One of their lives* is what you want.

This is structurally ambiguous (does it mean "the life of one of them", or "one from among all the lives of any of them"?), but I can't find any actual ambiguity in the meaning.

**Edit:** an example that might be actually ambiguous is *One of their children*. It could mean "One from among all the children of any of them", or "(All) the children of one of them". I think the first interpretation is much more likely - most people would word the second another way, to avoid the ambiguity - but the second interpration is possible.

Comment: Thank you, Colin! Would it be "One of **your** lives" if I were talking to them?

Comment: @TasneemZH: Yes.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example to explain the possible ambiguity. Could you please clarify the issues that exist in my phrase "One's life of them"? I know it is stated awkwardly but is it at least grammatically correct? And does it indicate any specific meaning?

Comment: @TasneemZH: no, I don't think it is grammatical. In current English, a noun phrase with a complement (such as "one of them", or "the Emperor of Japan" is made possessive as a whole ("one of their" or "The Emperor of Japan's"), not by making the head noun possessive  (*"one's or them" or *"The Emperor's of Japan").

Comment: Great explanation! I'll keep that in mind.